# How does one properly install reactGA with npm?

Tags: reactjs, react-ga

I created a react app with React 18, but when I try installing `reactGA` using `npm install react-ga --save`, I get errors:
[image: terminal screen shot]

I tried reinstalling nodejs but nothing seems to be working, I can install other packages but for some reason `react-ga` is not working.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says react-ga requires React 15, 16 or 17.

Downgrade your React version to 17. 18 was just released yesterday - the ecosystem hasn't caught up.